# import jsPdf in react native

Tags: react-native, jspdf

currently we are using react-native0.63.4 we are trying to implement jsPdf in our project through npm and the installation of jsPdf 2.5.1 was getting succesfull and we are getting this error
" Error: While trying to resolve module `canvg` from file `D:\Emx-Elb\emx-elb\node_modules\jspdf\dist\jspdf.es.min.js`, the package `...\node_modules\canvg\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`...\node_modules\canvg\lib\index.cjs`. Indeed, none of these files exist:"
while trying to import like this import { jsPDF } from "jspdf"

I am trying to save user data in the pdf format by using jsPdf